# Simple XML not reading https url fields php:Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Am using SimpleXML to read my xml file. When I remove my Image tags it reads the information. My URLS are HTTPS and I would like to read them. I have used various character escape characters but to no success.

Here is simple xml i mad: 
`url_xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Image>
<ImageID>https://x.ctrl.com/Image.ashx?Id=e1f47a89-c289-43e1-a2c2-0d35196a97ee&userId=7414</ImageID>
<ImageURL>https://x.ctrl.com/Image.ashx?Id=e1f47a89-c289-43e1-a2c2-0d35196a97ee&userId=7414</ImageURL>
<TempImageURL>https://x.ctrl.com/Image.ashx?Id=e1f47a89-c289-43e1-a2c2-0d35196a97ee&userId=7414</TempImageURL>
</Image>
```

`xml php script`

```
<?php
$xml_source='url_xml.xml';

@$xml=simplexml_load_file($xml_source);
echo $xml->getName() . "<br>";

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
  {
      echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br>";
   }

?>
```

PHP ERROR:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem on your XML with escaping.

Escape **`&`** with **`&amp;`**

Like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Image>
    <ImageID>https://x.ctrl.com/Image.ashx?Id=e1f47a89-c289-43e1-a2c2-0d35196a97ee&amp;userId=7414</ImageID>
    <ImageURL>https://x.ctrl.com/Image.ashx?Id=e1f47a89-c289-43e1-a2c2-0d35196a97ee&amp;userId=7414</ImageURL>
    <TempImageURL>https://x.ctrl.com/Image.ashx?Id=e1f47a89-c289-43e1-a2c2-0d35196a97ee&amp;userId=7414</TempImageURL>
</Image>
```

Because of this your XML was unable to get parsed, also remove the error suppression operator **`@`** from your **`@$xml`**, just load it as `$xml=simplexml_load_file($xml_source);` so you can know where you went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your input I have tried running a function in my php file that would open the xml file and str_replace but still throws the `Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in`. Are there any tips I could try?

Answer (score 1):

My educated guess (since you call [getName()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getname.php) twice and you've stripped line number from the error message) is that the error is here:

```
@$xml=simplexml_load_file($xml_source);
echo $xml->getName() . "<br>";
```

Since [simplexml_load_file()](https://www.php.net/simplexml_load_file) can only return a non-object on failure, I guess that's what happening. You either don't have a well-formed XML document or the given file is not readable. According to a random XML validator I found in Google, it's the first case:

> **The document is NOT well-formed**
> Reference to entity "userId" must end with the ';' delimiter.
>
> ```
>  .../Image.ashx?Id=e1f47a89-c289-43e1-a2c2-0d35196a97ee&userId=7414</ImageID>
>                                                               ^
> ```

(You can normally just load the XML file in a web browser; it'll notify you about errors.)

Most XML parsers (including SimpleXML) only work on well-formed data.

Since `&` has a special meaning in XML context, you need to encode it as `&amp;`. If the XML is yours, I'd advise against generating XML code manually.